# Wordpress contact form with registration details in csv format

Tags: wordpress

On my wordpress site, I would like to have register form with few text fields, I know we can do this with contact form available on wordpress admin panel that simply emails the participant or the contact details to the given email id, but is there any way we can ahve .csv file generated of the all the details entered on the contact form, and I can download it anytime from the admin panel ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **contact form 7** plugin for your registration form, you need to install **Contact form DB** plugin which captures all the entries and give you the option to download in excel,csv..etc